# Minimax for Avalanche version of Mancala: My code returns a bad move

Tags: javascript, minimax

I have been making a mancala bot using a minimax algorithm. It works for the first bit but it often just gives an output landing on a blank space. Anyone have any idea how to fix this so it plays well?

Here is my code:

```
let final;
function increment(board, ltif, player, re) {
    let a = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < board[ltif]; i++) {
        if((player && (ltif+i+a+1)%14 == 13) || (!player && (ltif+i+a+1)%14 == 6)) {
            a += 1;
        }
        board[(ltif + i + a + 1)%14] += 1;
    }
    const bltif = board[ltif];
    board[ltif] = 0;
    let ans;
    board[(bltif + ltif + a)%14] == 1 || (bltif + ltif + a)%14 == 6 || (bltif + ltif + a)%14 == 13 ? ans = board : ans = increment(board, (bltif + ltif + a)%14, player);
    if(((bltif + ltif + a)%14 == 6 || (bltif + ltif + a)%14 == 13) && !re) {
        ans = 2;;
        }
    if(board[(bltif + ltif + a)%14] == 1 && !re) {
        ans = 3;
    }
    return ans;
}
function minimax(board, depth, player) {
    if(board[6] > 24) {
        return 15;
    }else if(board[13] > 24) {
        return -15;
    }else if(board[6] == 24 && board[13] == 24) {
        return 0;
    }else if(depth === 0) {
        return Math.floor((board[6]-board[13])/2);
    }
    let avail = board.map((element, index) => (element !== 0 && ((index < 6 && player)|| (index < 13 && index > 6 && !player)) ? index : -1)).filter(element => element !== -1);
    if(player) {
        let maxEval = [-Infinity];
        for(let i = 0; i < avail.length; i++) {
            let tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, false);
            let Eval;
            if(tboard == 2) {
                Eval = 13;
                tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, true);
            }else if(tboard == 3) {
                Eval = -13;
                tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, true);
            }else{
                Eval = minimax(tboard, depth - 1, false);
            }
            maxEval = [Math.max(Eval, maxEval[0]),avail[i],tboard];
        }
        final = [maxEval[1], maxEval[2]];
        return maxEval[0];
    }else{
        let minEval = +Infinity;
        for(let i = 0; i < avail.length; i++) {
            let tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, false);
            let Eval;
            if(tboard == 2) {
                Eval = 13;
                tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, true);
            }else if(tboard == 3) {
                Eval = -13;
                tboard = increment(board.slice(), avail[i], player, true);
            }else{
                Eval = minimax(tboard, depth - 1, false);
            }
            minEval = Math.min(Eval, minEval);
        }
    return minEval;
    }
}
minimax([
    5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0,
    3, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5,
    5, 0
  ], 9, true);
console.log(final);
```

It runs out of a text based editor so that's why the output is into console and it only checks one board then you have to input another. Also just to clarify it is the avalanche version of mancala.

I do not have much experience using a minimax algorithm so if anyone has any insight into the problem that would be very helpful.

One example of this is that when given the board state:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0]
```

...it tells me to move the one on the 4th spot of the array so 5 from the right which gives this output:

```
[1, 6, 6, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0]
```

There are much better possible moves (like index 2) and I have no idea why the algorithm is selecting this. Also, the minimax algorithm I am using does not use alpha-beta pruning which is intended and not just a mistake in the code.

Comment: Please include the rules of the game and what would be the expected move and why.

Comment: I don't understand some of the logic you have implemented, but this might relate to some specific rules. It is important to include the exact rules you are implementing.

Comment: The way it works is you pick a spot on your side of the mancala board and the put on piece in every space after except for your opponents point zone until you run out. Afterwards you do the same with the space you land in until you land in a blank space or your own zone. If you land in a blank space you end your turn and if you end in your own zone you can choose any spot on your side to repeat the process with. If there is only pieces on your opponents side you can then move pieces on their side.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the rules there? Please explain where you implement the "if you end in your own zone" rule, and what the "magic" values 2 and 3 mean in your code (that has no comments and uses variable names that mean nothing to me, like what is "ltif"?). Can you add code comments? Why is a call of `increment` made *after* you have already determined the `Eval` value? What is the use of that? ...etc, ...etc.

Comment: The values of two and three are just arbitrary numbers chosen as out puts from the increment function in certain cases. The increment function returns a two when the end spot is your own zone and a 3 if it is a blank and in both cases if re which signifies it is sending it back through is not true.  In either of those cases it still needs a board so sends it back through after setting the value of eval to get the board this time with re set to true. Also ltif is a variable I chose to represent the value to increment from which is given in the minimal function.

Comment: Oh wow, so you use the same function to first return a value of 2 or 3 and then a second time to return the board? That is very unconventional, but I get it. I might prepare an answer to your question.

Comment: The main reason for that is since the values of two and three are only sometimes returned and are based on aspects already defined in the increment function so it didn’t make sense in my mind to recreate those aspects another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following issues in your implementation:

- Note that in `minimax` the first call of `increment` can only return 2 or 3. This is because `increment` will keep making recursive calls as long as the stop condition is not true. And when the stop *is* true, it returns 2 or 3 (in case `re` is false). By consequence, `minimax` will *never* make a recursive call with `depth-1`!  I would suggest to solve this as follows. Don't stop the recursion when `tboard == 3`. This is the case when a turn ends "normally", i.e. without the right to get an extra turn. In that case there is no reason why the recursion should stop. So make the recursive call in that case, instead of setting `Eval` to -13.
- `if(board[(bltif + ltif + a)%14] == 1 && !re)` is a bug. This should be an `else` because you don't want to overwrite `ans` with 3 when it was already set to 2, but the player's store happens to have 1 stone in it. And in the `else` case you can be sure that this condition is true, so it is not needed to evaluate it. Alternatively, you could `return ans` in the `if` block so there is no risk of overwriting that `ans` with 3.
- `maxEval = [Math.max(Eval, maxEval[0]),avail[i],tboard];` is wrong, because it updates the second and third entry of `maxEval` even when `Eval` is *worse*. This way you lose the move that was already associated with the best score. You should only update `maxEval[1]` and `maxEval[2]` when `Eval` is better than `maxEval[0]`. (I would also suggest using a plain object for this instead of an array. With a plain object we can give meaningful names to the three components).
- `final = [maxEval[1], maxEval[2]];` is wrong because it is also executed at deeper levels in the recursion tree, overwriting the result that was already registered at the top of the recursion tree, which is the result you are really interested in. The deeper problem here is that `final` should not be a global variable which `minimax` is altering as a "side-effect". This is bad practice. Instead, have `minimax` *return* that information.
- For both the maximizing and minimizing user your code gives a score of 13 if they played a good move (as they achieved an extra turn). This cannot be right. The value should be -13 for the minimizing user, otherwise it will actually serve as a *bad* move!

#### Other remarks:

- Use more descriptive variables names. For example, `numStones` instead of `bltif`.
- Avoid repeating the same expression like `(bltif + ltif + a)%14`. Instead have a variable dedicated to represent that value. You should only need one occurrence of the `% 14` operation in your code.
- Avoid calling `increment` twice on the same board only to get two different pieces of information from it, based on `re`. If you would just store `board.slice()` in a variable before calling `increment`, you would already have the mutated board after the `increment` call. That way you don't need the call with `re` set to true, and can get rid of that parameter.
- Avoid using ["magic numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). For instance, the return values 2 and 3 should be explained and better be replaced with constants that have descriptive names. However, in this particular case we could just use a boolean instead (with a descriptive name), which indicates whether the player has the right to an extra move or not.
- Don't perform an assignment (like `ans = board`) inside a larger expression. Convert such an expression to an assignment, where the right hand expression has the necessary logic.
- Use `camelCase` for variables, so don't use `Eval` as a name. I would suggest `score` (as `eval` is already used for a native function).
- To determine `avail`, don't use `.map`, but use `.filter` immediately. That way you don't need the virtual -1 value.

#### Corrected code

Here is the code I ended up with while applying the above corrections and suggestions:

```js
// Don't use magic values, but instead define constants with meaningful names:
const STORE = { false: 13, true: 6 }; // Per player: the index of their store
const STORES = new Set(Object.values(STORE));
      // Per player: the indices of their pits 
const PITS = { false: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], true: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] };
const NUM_STONES = 48;
const GOOD_SCORE = NUM_STONES / 4 + 1; // Better score than max heuristic score
const MAX_SCORE = GOOD_SCORE + 1; // Overall best possible score

// The function increment returns a boolean that is true when the move ended with a stone 
//     in the player's store, giving them a right to an extra move.
//     The given board is mutated, so the caller can see the effect of the move in that board.
function increment(board, startPit, player) {
    const numStones = board[startPit];
    let lastPit = startPit;
    for (let i = 1; i <= board[startPit]; i++) {
        // We can use a conditional inline expression to decide to add an extra 1 or not.
        lastPit = (lastPit + 1 + (lastPit + 1 == STORE[!player])) % board.length;
        board[lastPit]++;
    }
    board[startPit] = 0;
    // There are three cases:
    if (lastPit === STORE[player]) { // Extra turn!
        return true;
    }
    if (board[lastPit] == 1) { // Normal move ended.
        return false;
    }
    // The turn is not finished yet; continue...
    return increment(board, lastPit, player);
}

function minimax(board, depth, player) {
    if (board[STORE[true]] * 2 > NUM_STONES) {
        // Maximizing player has more than half of the stones, so they won the game.
        return MAX_SCORE;
    } else if (board[STORE[false]] * 2 > NUM_STONES) {
        // Minimizing player has more than half of the stones, so they won the game.
        return -MAX_SCORE;
    } else if (board[STORE[true]] + board[STORE[false]] == NUM_STONES) {
        // All stones are in the stores, and both players have an equal amount: it's draw
        return 0;
    } else if (depth === 0) {
        // Search must stop here. Give a heuristic value:
        return Math.floor((board[STORE[true]] - board[STORE[false]]) / 2);
    }
    // Get the player's own pits that have at least one stone in it:
    const availablePits = PITS[player].filter(pit => board[pit]); 
    if (player) { // Maximizing player
        let best = { score: -Infinity };
        for (const pit of availablePits) {
            const newBoard = board.slice(); // Keep a reference to the new board
            const extraTurn = increment(newBoard, pit, player);
            const score = extraTurn ? GOOD_SCORE // We get an extra turn (good!), so we will not look deeper
                                      // Otherwise: no extra turn. Continue the recursion.
                                    : minimax(newBoard, depth - 1, false).score; // Get score component
            if (score > best.score) {
                // Only make updates when the score is better
                best = { score, pit, board: newBoard };
            }
        }
        return best; // Don't alter a global. Just return complete information: {score, pit, board}.
    } else {
        let best = { score: +Infinity };
        for (const pit of availablePits) {
            const newBoard = board.slice(); 
            const extraTurn = increment(newBoard, pit, player);
            const score = extraTurn ? -GOOD_SCORE // Minimizing user wants a negative value here!
                                    : minimax(newBoard, depth - 1, false).score;
            if (score < best.score) {
                best = { score, pit, board: newBoard };
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}

// Minimax should *return* the information instead of setting a global variable.
const { score, pit, board } = minimax([ 
    // Layout was confusing. This seems clearer:
    5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0,     3, 
    5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5,     0
  ], 9, true);

console.log(`The best move is from pit ${pit}. It got score ${score}, and leads to this board: ${board}`);
```

The algorithm now returns as best move, pit number 2. I didn't play this game enough to judge whether that is really the best move or not.

Comment: Thank you trincot. Also yes two is widely considered the best first move.

Comment: Some values where a little off and I added some more checks so it finds a better move and not the first one of a score by increasing the score range but was a very helpful base.